# How do I display empty fields?

Tags: display-suite

I have redesigned the layout of the page using the display suite module. When I go to the node, I see empty fields are not there. I like to see the empty fields on the node. I have been looking for the settings and I could not find it. How can I display empty fields?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_fields

Comment: @Drupol Did you look at the module suggested by Patrick Ryan? Did you try it already, but it doesn't meet your needs? Are you looking for code to implement in a module?

Answer (score 1):

Display suite accepts custom templates that override the default layouts.

An easy way to achieve what you want if you are using a custom theme is add a custom template override for whatever DS layout - 2 column for example - you are trying to change.

By default I think the DS templates don't show empty fields.

eg in twig:

```
{% if user_picture is not empty %}
  {{ user_picture }}
{% endif %}
```

If you always them them to be rendered - or at least some layout code around them you can add custom markup.

[This](https://www.drupal.org/node/1098068) article discusses the basics. It is about drupal 7 but drupal 8 matters are discussed in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

I never did it I have a small though...

Write a customer formatter (module /custom_formatters) for this field which outputs for the length of the field &nsbp;

Another option is maybe to add custom tokens which a writing blank spaces and set the initial value to this token.